# ASP.NET MVC partial rendering issue using Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

I have **_Layout.cshtml** defined for my mvc application, which is shown below:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
@using Webdiyer.WebControls.Mvc;

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>   
    @RenderSection("HeaderContent", false)
</head>

<body> 
    @RenderBody() 
</body>
</html>
```

On the page **SomePage.cshtml**, I have included the layout, and also included the partial rendering construction, because I want my **_MailForm.cshtml** to be rendered on this page:

```
@{
   View.Title = "page";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Html.Partial("_MailForm")
```

My **_MailForm.cshtml** file looks following:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<CMS.Models.Mail.MailModel>

@section HeaderContent
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/mail.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}

<form>...</form>
```

The **HeaderContent** section declared in **_MailForm.cshtml**, suppose to be rendered from **_Layout.cshtml** and load **mail.js** script. The script is actually **not** loaded and because of that my form logic is not working. If I move that **HeaderContent** section from **_MailForm.cshtml** to **SomePage.cshtml**, everything works because mvc loads the script.

But how to load that script from inside **_MailForm.cshtml** file?

Regards

Comment: This is actually by design. The sections can only populate the direct parent...I ran into this same issue, as well.

Comment: Is there any workaround for that, or some different approach to solve the issue ? Moving that section to direct child of its rendering parent is the only solution ?

Comment: Well, the simplest method would be to combine all your javascript into a single file. That would decrease pageloads bandwidth and generally make it better for the end user as they have to load a javascript file only once...however that's not the solution you're looking for. Since the `SomePage.cshtml` file has the partial page hard-coded I would say including your required script in that page is ok for now. Also, it's OK to put scripts in the body tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'll rewrite here the comment written by **@BuildStarted**, which is actually answer for my question:

*"This is actually by design. The sections can only populate the direct parent. (...) the simplest method [to solve the issue] would be to combine all your javascript into a single file. That would decrease pageloads bandwidth and generally make it better for the end user as they have to load a javascript file only once...however that's not the solution you're looking for. Since the SomePage.cshtml file has the partial page hard-coded I would say including your required script in that page is ok for now. Also, it's OK to put scripts in the body tag."*

Comment: But what about the javascript's related style or stylesheets?, some javascript plugins such as jquery ui stuff, dropdownmenus and others are tightly bound to css and styles which cannot be put directly into the body.

Comment: Besides, in most cases you don't have access to the body at all from a partial view. Any solution?